# Is there a way to leave the Okular highlighting tool on permanently?

Tags: pdf, highlight, okular

I found out I can highlight pdfs with okular in-file by the review tool, but everytime I use the highlighter, it gets turned off afterwards again, so to highlight the next piece of text I have to activate it again.

I would like to change this behaviour to 'toggle' on off by clicking (or pressing 4), and not have it turn off automatically.

I saw [here](https://superuser.com/questions/584017/customise-okular-to-modify-highlight-tool-properties) that the tools can be modified, but it doesn't mention toggling.

Comment: This definitely does not belong on this site, if you want someone to code a feature for you hire a developer. if you would like help after you have attempted to show what you have attempted how it's not working and perhaps people here will be able to help, do this as a new question and leave this closed or delete it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Double-clicking the tool solves it, as I found in a [Bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331081) pointing to the manual.

Comment: cannot believe it was that simple :|

Comment: can I ask how you found out? I don't see this shortcut pointed out anywhere.
thanks, btw.

Comment: As I wrote, the bug report points to the manual. if you search for "highlight" in the manual, there's a description of double-clicking, I found it on page 19. I found the bug report by ddging (duckduckgoing) "okular keep highlight on" or something like it. hope that answers your question, but I agree - It's  a 'kind of hidden' feature as there's no menu switch or so in the okular interface.

Comment: For those who can't find the highlight tool : see https://askubuntu.com/questions/376136/cannot-find-highlight-tool-in-adobe-reader-or-okular.   you can press F6 to access the tool. Nowhere in the menu is it shown.

Answer (score 9):

You have to select the Pin button ( its the one at the right most) and then click the Highlighter button
[image]

Comment: That's the way now!

Comment: Which version of Okular are you using? On v 1.9.3 on Ubuntu I can't see that toolbar. Is there a way of keeping the highlighter active with shortcuts?

Comment: I'm using Okular version 20.12.3 on ubuntu. If you don't see the toolbar, you have to Tool -> Annotations

Answer (score 1):

Double-click didn't work for me.

Clicking:

- "Highlighter"
- and then "Keep Active"
  worked for me

(Press F6 if you don't see the "Highlighter button")

Comment: I am not able to see "Keep Active". Where exactly is it?
Edit: Okay, there's a "pin" button in the Annotations toolbar. Once you click that, Okular does not shift back  anymore.

Comment: It is found in a popup menu under two tiny right carets (>>) on the far right of the toolbar menu along the top